# Convert workspace (WINCE device com) to workspace compatible for PC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I have created a ATL COM workspace for a WIN CE device. The COM dll generated by the workspace is compatible for the Win CE device processor. Debugging in the Win CE device is very time consuming as it involves (copying the files through ftp, registering the COM in the device using telnet and debug the dll through remote debugging)

Is it possible to convert the workspace by changing some projectsetting to build it to run in my PC? 
What other options are available to reduce the debug time?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the Configuration Manager and add a new configuration for Win32 or x64. You may choose to copy settings from your WinCE project, but adjusting them to work on the PC will not necessarily be easier than starting over. You just have to decide for your particular case.